# How does the dlmMLE function work?

Tags: dlm

How does the dlmMLE in package dlm in R work?

Are the maximum likelihood estimates coming from the Kalman filter or by numerical optimization. If it is using numerical optimization,what is the algorithm being used? In the code that follows,dlmMLE is used prior to dlmFilter,so I would think that dlmMLE does NOT use the kalman recursion.

Also the delta method is being used after dlmMLE,which means that a sequence of random variables is being built by dlmMLE.Can someone say a few words about this? What posterior density will this sequence of random variables converge to?

```
library(dlm)
# simulate AR(1) process  
# phi = .8, sig2 = .25
nobs <- 250
yt <- arima.sim(n=nobs,list(ar=.8,ma=0),sd=.5)
# set parameter restrictions 
parm_rest <- function(parm){
return( c(exp(parm[1])/(1+exp(parm[1])),exp(parm[2])) ) 
}

# set up SS model
ssm1 <- function(parm){
parm <- parm_rest(parm)
return( dlm(FF=1,V=0,GG=parm[1],W=parm[2],
            m0=0,C0=solve(1-parm[1]^2)*parm[2]) )
}

# estimate parameters
fit1 <- dlmMLE(y=yt,parm=c(0,1),build=ssm1,hessian=T)

# get estimates 
coef <- parm_rest(fit1$par)
# get standard errors using delta method
dg1 <- exp(fit1$par[1])/(1+exp(fit1$par[1]))^2
dg2 <- exp(fit1$par[2])
dg <- diag(c(dg1,dg2))
var <- dg%*%solve(fit1$hessian)%*%dg
# print results
coef; sqrt(diag(var))


mydlmModel<- ssm1(fit1$par)

filt<-dlmFilter(yt,mydlmModel)
```